# 4-bit Ripple Carry adder testbench in vivado

Tags: if-statement, syntax, vivado

The code below is for a 4-bit ripple carry adder testbench. it's giving me 8 syntax errors, 4 near end and 4 near else. i don't know what these errors are referring to, what to do need to fix?

```
module rca_dataflow_tb(

reg [3:0] a,
reg [3:0] b,
reg cin,
reg [3:0] s,
reg cout

);

rca_dataflow uut(.a(a),.b(b),.cin(cin),.s(s),.cout(cout));

initial 
begin

#20
a = 4'b0;
b = 4'b0;
cin = 1'b0;
#20
if (s == 4'b0000 & cout == 1'b0) 
$display("Test Passed")
else 
$display("Test Failed")
end

#20
a = 4'b0010;
b = 4'b0000;
cin = 1'b0;
#20
if (s == 4'b0010 & cout == 1'b0)
$display("Test Passed")
else 
$display("Test Failed")
end


end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time also list the syntax errors please.

However in this case it is rather obvious: you have extra `end` statements in there. The syntax is:

```
if (condition)
    statement_or_block;
else
    statement_or_block;
```

Also (Thank you Kevin!) your display is missing a semicolon at the end and
your top level test bench should have no ports. All signals are local:

```
module rca_dataflow_tb;
reg [3:0] a;
reg [3:0] b;
// etc.
```

Also I suggest you use conditional AND and not logical AND:
`if (s == 4'b0010 && cout == 1'b0)`

<sub>By the way you can use logical AND if you first convert the expressions to single bits:

`if ( (s==4'b0010) & (cout==1'b0) )`</sub>

Answer (score 0):

There are some very basic mistakes in your code.

1. You are not using `;` at the end of all the 4 `$display` statements
2. You can not use `reg` as a type for your port declarations. In fact, since this is your TB there will be no ports. You can just do `module rca_dataflow_tb();` and shift all the reg statements outside
3. Use `reg` data type for inputs to your DUT and `wire` for your DUT outputs

This should fix the issues. Let me know if you still face issues

Comment: Sorry, your answer disappeared (showed as deleted) thus I added your comments to mine.

Comment: I've done what you suggested, however there is a new error that says syntax error near 'rca_dataflow_tb'

Comment: Did you put a `;` in the end of `module rca_dataflow_tb();`? Sorry had a typo in the answer which i have edited now